# Magento 2 - Can't override pdf invoice class

Tags: magento2, php, invoice, pdf, override-model

I'm trying to customize the pdf invoice template, so I want to override the class that generate the pdf.

I found that these class create the pdf:

- `Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice.php`
- `Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\AbstractPdf.php`
- `Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Items\Invoice\DefaultInvoice.php`

Then I check in the code and I found that the method I need to override are only in `AbstractPdf.php` and `Invoice.php` but the last one extend the abstract class so I decide to override the class `Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice.php`

To override what I need I created a module `<Vendor>_<Module>` with these files:

`<Vendor>_<Module>\registration.php`

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    '<Vendor>_<Module>',
    __DIR__
);
```

`<Vendor>_<Module>\etc\module.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="<Vendor>_<Module>" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Sales"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

`<Vendor>_<Module>\etc\di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference type="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice" for="<Vendor>\<Module>\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice"/>
</config>
```

`<Vendor>_<Module>\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice.php`

```
<?php

namespace <Vendor>\<Module>\Model\Order\Pdf;

use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Config;

class Invoice extends \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice
{

    /**
     * InvoicePdf constructor.
     * @param \Magento\Payment\Helper\Data $paymentData
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\StringUtils $string
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem
     * @param Config $pdfConfig
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Total\Factory $pdfTotalFactory
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\ItemsFactory $pdfItemsFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface $localeDate
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface $inlineTranslation
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Address\Renderer $addressRenderer
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Locale\ResolverInterface $localeResolver
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Payment\Helper\Data $paymentData,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\StringUtils $string,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem,
        Config $pdfConfig,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Total\Factory $pdfTotalFactory,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\ItemsFactory $pdfItemsFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface $localeDate,
        \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface $inlineTranslation,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Address\Renderer $addressRenderer,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\Locale\ResolverInterface $localeResolver,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        parent::__construct(
            $paymentData,
            $string,
            $scopeConfig,
            $filesystem,
            $pdfConfig,
            $pdfTotalFactory,
            $pdfItemsFactory,
            $localeDate,
            $inlineTranslation,
            $addressRenderer,
            $storeManager,
            $localeResolver,
            $data
        );
    }

    /**
     * Draw header for item table
     *
     * @param \Zend_Pdf_Page $page
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _drawHeader(\Zend_Pdf_Page $page)
    {
        // my custom code
    }

    public function getPdf($invoices = [])
    {

        // my custom code
    }

    protected function insertOrder(&$page, $obj, $putOrderId = true)
    {
        // my custom code
    }

    /**
     * Return total list
     *
     * @return \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Total\DefaultTotal[] Array of totals
     */
    protected function _getTotalsList()
    {
        // my custom code
    }

    /**
     * Insert totals to pdf page
     *
     * @param  \Zend_Pdf_Page $page
     * @param  \Magento\Sales\Model\AbstractModel $source
     * @return \Zend_Pdf_Page
     */
    protected function insertTotals($page, $source)
    {
        // my custom code
    }

    /**
     * Metodo per ottenere la data dell'ordine
     *
     * @param $order
     * @return string
     */
    protected function getOrderDate($order)
    {
        // my custom code
    }

}
```

Finally I called these command:

- `php bin/magento module:enable --clear-static-content <Vendor>_<Module>`
- `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`
- `php bin/magento setup:di:compile`
- `php bin/magento cache:flush`

But when I go to admin and I tryed to print an invoice I still get the original template. I also tryed to put a `die` on construct of my custom class, but nothing appends.

Comment: ,How you resolve error "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function render() on null in vendor/magento/module-sales/Controller/Adminhtml/Invoice/AbstractInvoice/PrintAction.php:59"

Comment: Have you overriden this file Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\AbstractPdf.php  ? invoice.php file can be override easily but this file not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below code for **di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice" type="<Vendor>\<Module>\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice"/>
</config>
```

I think you interchanged **type** and **for**

Answer (score 1):

Check Your **di.xml** at

> Vendor_Module\etc\di.xml

It should like this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice" type="<Vendor>\<Module>\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice"/>
</config>
```